# Should an explicit copy constructor be ignored?

Tags: initialization, c++14, explicit

Here is small example which demonstrates an unclear moment

```
struct CL
{
    CL(){}
    CL(int){}
    explicit CL(const CL&){}
};

int main() {
    CL cl1;
    CL cl2=5;     //(1)
    CL cl3=(CL)5; //(2)
    return 0;
}
```

The CL class have conversion constructor from int and copy constructor marked as explicit. In (1) case 5 (int) implicitly converted to CL and then cl2 is direct-initialized. In (2) case cl3 is copy-initialized. In both cases explicit copy-constructor must be involved. But different compilers give different results:

clang and VS: first case is right, but second is wrong
gcc: both cases are wrong

I think clang and VS are right because according to Standard "explicit" keyword prevents using a constructor in a copy-initialization, but not in a direct-initialization and gcc is wrong because direct-initialization is applied in (1) case.
Who of the compilers is right?

Comment: [Bug 54521](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54521), fixed recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ 12.3.1 [class.conv.ctor]/p2:

> An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so only where the
>   direct-initialization syntax (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are explicitly used.

Example 1:

```
CL cl2 = 5;
```

§ 8.5 [dcl.init]/p17:

> The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its
>   argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified
>   version of the destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call (which is the
>   temporary for the constructor case) **is then used to direct-initialize**, according to the rules above,
>   the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization.

In direct-initialization, `explicit` constructors can be considered, so the error is not expected. GCC trunk already compiles this example [successfully](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lZOTnSDH0rHdeTdw). This was [bug 54521](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54521).

---

Example 2:

```
CL cl3 = (CL)5;
```

In this case, that cast syntax performs a `static_cast`:

§ 5.2.9 [expr.static.cast]/p4:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)`
>   if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an
>   explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using **the temporary
>   variable as the result of the conversion.**

The rhs is of type `CL`, and the (copy-)initialization requires a non-`explicit` constructor, thus the error is expected.