# How is that an explicit constructor is used in an implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, explicit

I am learning about `explicit` keyword in C++ using the resources listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean/121163#121163) says:

> Prefixing the explicit keyword to the constructor prevents the compiler from using that constructor for implicit conversions.

---

Now I wrote the following example that uses the `explicit` copy constructor `B::B(const B&)` in an implicit conversion. The example is as follows:  [MRE with C++14 and -fno-elide-constructors flag](https://godbolt.org/z/vbd61WEvT)

```
struct A {
    A()
    {
    std::cout<<"A's default ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout<<"A's copy ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout<<"B default ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    B(A)
    {
        std::cout<<"B's parametrized ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    explicit B(const B&)
    {
        std::cout<<"explicit B copy ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    B x;
    //B a = x; //this fails AS EXPECTED

    A y;

    B p = y; //Why doesn't this fail as well? This uses the copy ctor in addition to the param ctor. How the explicit copy ctor is used here in implicit conversion

   
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
B default ctor called
A's default ctor called
A's copy ctor called
B's parametrized ctor called
explicit B copy ctor called   <--------------HOW IS THAT EXPLICIT CTOR IS USED HERE IN IMPLICIT CONVERSION?
```

So my question is that how is it possible to use an explicit copy ctor in the above implicit conversion. I mean to my current understanding I expected `B p = y;` to fail just like the copy initialization `B a = x;`  fails. I want to know is this allowed by the standard or is it a compiler bug.

##### Note

Note the use of `-fno-elide-constructors` flag in my given demo.

Comment: `B(A)` is a so-called converting constructor. Why do you think `explicit B(const B&)` would need to be called? Are you confusing assignment with initialization? `B p = y;` is only initialization of `p` from `y`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know `B p = y;` is Initialisation. Read carefully my question it is asking why the explicit copy constructor is called for `B p= y;`

Comment: @Kal Because here **direct initialization** will be used to initialize `p` from the prvalue and in direct initialization explicit ctors can be used. See my answer below.

Comment: oh i see. Cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/xr5M6M4Tv

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Note the use of the -fno-elide-constructors flag in OP's demo.

Comment: @AnoopRana the link doesnt work for me and same results with the flag https://godbolt.org/z/b8T6fsEKz

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Looks like Firefox default tracking protection breaks wandbox. Anyway, newest GCC uses C++17 by default IIRC, changing it to C++14 makes the result as in OP's output: https://godbolt.org/z/e7a6hdz48

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think you missed the `C++14` tag in OP's question. With C++14 and -fno-elide-constructors flag it is reproducible on godbolt: [MRE with C++14 and -fno-elide-constructors flag](https://godbolt.org/z/vbd61WEvT)

Comment: Dup of [Should an explicit copy constructor be ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427433/should-an-explicit-copy-constructor-be-ignored)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know is this allowed by the standard or is it a compiler bug.

This is well-formed and is allowed by the standard as explained below.

The behavior of your program can be understood using [dcl.init#17.6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#17.6.2) which states:

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences
> that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
> is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is
> chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the
> initialization is ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its
> argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified
> version of the destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. The **result of the call (which is the
> temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize**, according to the rules above,
> **the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization**.

(emphasis mine)

Let's apply this to your example.

In the given example(`B p = y;` in particular) the *source type* is `A` while the destination type is `B`. Now there is a user-defined conversion available from the source type to the destination type using the non-explicit parameterized ctor `B::B(A)` which will be used here.

This non-explicit ctor will be called with the initializer expression `y` as its argument. Moreover, this call is a *prvalue* of type `B`.

The important thing to note here is that this call will be used to **direct-initialize** the object named `p`. And since in direct initialization context the explicit ctor can be used, therefore the explicit copy ctor can and will be used here.

The effect is **as-if** we're writing:

```
B p{/*prvalue of type B obtained from call to parameterized ctor*/};
```